# Css Link in HTML in Spring

Tags: html, css, spring

[image]

I have this CSS problem. I can't link it with my HTML file. I'm using a template from Colorlib and I can't link it. So I hope I will get an answer thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your href try adding ./

href=./css/styles.css

Also, in the future it is always best practice to copy/paste your code in your question and not just simply add an image.

Comment: I wanted to show everyone the structure of my project.

Comment: Do I add another link or in the same link ?

Comment: use the same link you have but just add the ./

Comment: hmmm try with no "." at all or if not then two ".."

Comment: ahhh i see why now its because you have it in a folder called colorlib...is there a reason why you have everything in that foldler? You can either take everything out of that folder or you'll have to add the folder name into your directory path

Comment: I just take everything out of that folder and still the same thing CSS not applied

Comment: Then did you remove the ../ ? Check out this site which further explains how to navigate file paths https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: It worked, I saw a youtube video ... so I had to move the whole css folder to the static folder and not the template folder